# Python Selenium Cant enter text to input

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to enter text into email input but it gives error

My Code

```
emailEntry = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Email Address']")
print(emailEntry)
emailEntry.send_keys("randommail@mail.com")
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0SNY.png)

Error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe you have to wait until it will be "interactable". OR maybe it is hidden and you have to remove other item to make it visible.

Comment: better show real URL and create `minimal working code` so we could copy and test it with real HTML